# Usage of wait system call in unix

Tags: unix

I am a bit confused about the syntax of wait. In Wikipedia it is given that the syntax of wait is **wait [pid]** whereas in the man page it is given that the syntax is **pid_t wait(int *status)**. I had an impression that we cannot call wait with the pid of a process and we needed to use waitpid for that. Could anyone please clear my doubt. Links to both the articles are given below:

1. [Wikipedia article on Wait](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wait_%28command%29) (command).
2. [Wikipedia article on Wait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wait_%28system_call%29) (system call).
3. [Unix man page on wait](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?wait%202) (system call).

Comment: One is a *function* used in programming, the other is a *command* used on the shell. They have nothing to do with each other. (ok, technically they do, the latter uses the former)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing the `wait` command in the shell with the similar functions used in programming. The shell uses one name, and decides what to do based on how it's used.

If you use the `wait` command with no arguments, it calls `wait()` to wait for any child to exit.

If you use the `wait` command with an argument, it calls `waitpid()` to wait for that specific PID to exit.